# Where can I post hardware-related questions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I want to post a question about hardware, I am assembling a PC and would love to get advice. Which would be the right place to ask?

Comment: FIngers crossed - downvotes!

Comment: Thank you Dronehinge!! [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/943204/assembling-a-desktop-for-the-first-time-require-advise)

Comment: You know this is in the pre-canned close reasons, right?

Comment: jonsharpe - I have no idea about what you are speaking of!

Comment: A PC, or a cyborg killing machine you want to send back to the 80s? -1 because I don't think we should help destroy humanity.

Comment: TZHX I believe we are just the stepping stone, for one I welcome our robot overlords :P

Comment: @Skynet Close > **off-topic because...** > *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User."*

Comment: I am not posting on stackoverflow but meta, Also I have posted the original question on super user.

Comment: @Skynet oh, for pity's... my point is that the close reasons on SO, which you have access to as a >3k user, include a close reason for questions like the one you want to ask *that tells you where it should go*. It is worth familiarising yourself with these. Another thing you should know by now: you need to add `@` to notify other users that you're addressing them.

Comment: Thanks jonsharpe, you enlightened me! Now I am sure of the second downvote!

Comment: www.reddit.com/r/buildapc is another great resource. Check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SuperUser](http://superuser.com) would be the place for such questions. To quote their "Help Center > Asking" page:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
>     *electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: Thanks mate, I have posted it on superuser :)

Comment: @Skynet It's off-topic on [su] as well as it stands - it is both opinion based **and** a hardware shopping recoomendation request.

Comment: Yes it has been put on hold there too, but neverthless I got some very valuable advise before they actually closed it :)